TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')
I got this error when trying to call handleOps function from ERC-4337. This is the code snippet from EntryPoint.sol contract
function handleOps(
        PackedUserOperation[] calldata ops,
        address payable beneficiary
    ) public nonReentrant {
        uint256 opslen = ops.length;
        UserOpInfo[] memory opInfos = new UserOpInfo[](opslen);

        unchecked {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < opslen; i++) {
                UserOpInfo memory opInfo = opInfos[i];
                (
                    uint256 validationData,
                    uint256 pmValidationData
                ) = _validatePrepayment(i, ops[i], opInfo);
                _validateAccountAndPaymasterValidationData(
                    i,
                    validationData,
                    pmValidationData,
                    address(0)
                );
            }

            uint256 collected = 0;
            emit BeforeExecution();

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < opslen; i++) {
                collected += _executeUserOp(i, ops[i], opInfos[i]);
            }

            _compensate(beneficiary, collected);
        }
    }

The PackedUserOperation is a struct with fields:
struct PackedUserOperation { address sender; uint256 nonce; bytes initCode; bytes callData; bytes32 accountGasLimits; uint256 preVerificationGas; bytes32 gasFees; bytes paymasterAndData; bytes signature; }
This is the code I use:
async function executeHandleOps(initCode, callData, viaPaymaster) {
const coder = defaultAbiCoder;
walletOwner = await simpleAccountFactoryContract.methods.getAddress(alicePublicKey, salt).call();
const nonce = await entryPointContract.methods.getNonce(walletOwner, 0).call();

const walletContract = new web3.eth.Contract(simpleAccountABI.abi, walletOwner);
if (callData != '0x')
    callData = await walletContract.methods.execute(WETH, 0, callData).encodeABI();

const accountGasLimit = hexZeroPad(hexlify(260611), 32);
const gasFees = hexZeroPad(hexlify(29964445250), 32);

var ops = {
    sender: walletOwner,
    nonce,
    initCode,
    callData,
    accountGasLimit,
    preVerificationGas: 53576,
    gasFees,
    paymasterAndData: '0x',
    signature: '0x'
};

if (viaPaymaster)
    ops.paymasterAndData = await composePaymasterAndData(ops);


const packUserOp = coder.encode(
    ['address', 'uint256', 'bytes', 'bytes', 'bytes32', 'uint256', 'bytes32', 'bytes', 'bytes'],
    [
        ops.sender,
        ops.nonce,
        ops.initCode,
        ops.callData,
        ops.accountGasLimit,
        ops.preVerificationGas,
        ops.gasFees,
        ops.paymasterAndData,
        ops.signature
    ]
);

const userOpHash = keccak256(packUserOp);

const enc = coder.encode(['bytes32', 'address', 'uint256'], [userOpHash, entryPointAddress, 31337]);
const encKecak = keccak256(enc);

const msg1 = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from('\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n', 'ascii'), Buffer.from(arrayify(encKecak))]);

const sig = ecsign(keccak256_buffer(msg1), Buffer.from(alicePrivateKey.slice(2), 'hex'));

ops.signature = toRpcSig(sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);

const handleOpsRawData = entryPointContract.methods.handleOps([ops], coordinatorPublicKey).encodeABI();
console.log("HandleOps Raw Data: ", handleOpsRawData);

const handleOpsops = {
    to: entryPointAddress,
    maxFeePerGas: 210000000000,
    gasLimit: 1e7,
    data: handleOpsRawData
}
const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(handleOpsops, coordinatorPrivateKey);
await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, function (error, hash) {
    if (!error) { console.log("Handleops Success --> ", hash); }
    else { console.log("Handleops Error --> ", error) }
});

}
`
Even though the params are not null or undefined, I got an error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toHexString')
    at isHexable (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/bytes/lib/index.js:9:21)    
    at arrayify (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/bytes/lib/index.js:69:9)     
    at FixedBytesCoder.encode (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/fixed-bytes.js:35:41)
    at /mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:74:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:71:33)
    at /mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:66:1    at /mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:74:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:71:33)
    at /mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:66:1    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:71:33)
    at /mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:66:1s:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/mnt/e/Downloads/ERC-4337/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:71:33)

Please help!
This is a sample of a userOp that I have logged before passing to the function:
Ops:  {
  sender: '0x4E67029B6e4396aC09d319EeF3FCEaD7990739D7',
  nonce: '0',
  initCode: '0x5fc8d32690cc91d4c39d9d3abcbd16989f8757075fbfb9cf00000000000000000000000070997970c51812dc3a010c7d01b50e0d17dc79c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002',       
  callData: '0x',
  accountGasLimit: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003fa03',
  preVerificationGas: 53576,
  gasFees: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006fa052642',
  paymasterAndData: '0x',
  signature: '0x289ba35db407608d668da536549773ff3447868627adeace412d65e1b4932e0f634b90ce059c7cab1e93f3f87023a2b9394c606a6a289c75787ebe73756a9b231b'
}

